# Why does my DataGrid display no rows when there are items in its bound data source?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, wpfdatagrid

When the main window - containing only my `DataGrid` shows, the `DataGrid` shows zero rows.

This is what my grid looks like:

```
<DataGrid                 
        AutoGenerateColumns="True"
        CanUserAddRows="False"
        CanUserReorderColumns="True"
        CanUserResizeColumns="True"
        DataContext="ClientListViewModel"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Source=RowItems}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Given Name" Binding="{Binding GivenName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Family Name" Binding="{Binding FamilyName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Gender" Binding="{Binding Gender, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date of Birth" Binding="{Binding DateOfBirth, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

In the `Source={Binding Source=RowItems}` the source is a property, `RowItems` on my main view model, `ClientListViewModel`.

The viewmodel has a `Read` method called in the ctor of `ClientListView`, my main view. When I debug this problem, I can see that the `RowItems` items source is correctly populated.

My initialization of the main view, the `UserControl` containing the `DataGrid` in question, looks like this:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    InitializeListView();
}

private void InitializeListView()
{
    var model = new ClientListViewModel();
    model.Read();
    var view = new ClientListView();
    view.DataContext = model;
    Content = view;
}
```

When I put a breakpoint straight after `model.Read();`, its `model.RowItems` property shows 12 items, yet the `DataGrid` shows no rows.

Why is my `DataGrid` rendering zero rows?

Comment: If you use `{Binding Source=RowItems}` you're not binding to a `RowItems` property of the `DataContext`, but rather to the whole binding source object, which you set explicitly and in this particular case is resolved to a string `"RowItems"` (note that it has 8 letters). You should set `Path` instead `Source` on your binding, i.e. `{Binding Path=RowItems}` or `{Binding RowItems}` in short.

Comment: @Grx70 Thanks, but I now have zero rows. If I mouse over the `RowItems` in ` ItemsSource="{Binding Path=RowItems}"` it shows me that that list property has 12 items, yet no rows!

Comment: That's because you explicitly set `DataGrid.DataContext="ClientListViewModel"`, which again resolves to a string `"ClientListViewModel"`, which does not have property named `RowItems`. If your `DataGrid` is part of your `ClientListView`, you can skip setting `DataGrid.DataContext` altogether (by default it will be inherited from `ClientListView`). Otherwise you should probably use proper binding which would resolve to an instance of `ClientListViewModel`. I suggest you (re)visit [Data Binding Overview](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-binding-overview) article.

Comment: Could you post your ClientListViewModel code? The issue could be with RowItems. If RowItems is not a type that implements change notification, you would not see your screen update when items get added to that list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the part are there, but they are not being arranged properly. To take advantage of DataBinding you need to follow a specific pattern. In this case you should follow these steps.

```
public MainWindow() {
    InitializeComponent();
    this.Clients = InitializeListView();
    this.DataContext = this;        
}

public ClientListViewModel Clients { get; set; }

private ClientListViewModel InitializeListView() {
    var model = new ClientListViewModel();
    model.Read();    
    return model;
}
```

And `MainWindow`, which you indicated only contains the `DataGrid` should bind its `ItemSource` accordingly to the properties of the `DataContext` of the view, which in this case is the `MainWindow` itself and the `DataGrid` will inherit as its `DataContext`

```
<DataGrid                 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        CanUserAddRows="False"
        CanUserReorderColumns="True"
        CanUserResizeColumns="True"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Clients.RowItems}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Given Name" Binding="{Binding GivenName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Family Name" Binding="{Binding FamilyName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Gender" Binding="{Binding Gender, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date of Birth" Binding="{Binding DateOfBirth, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: You are setting `Clients` after setting `DataContext = this` and there is no change notification for that property, so WPF won't notice the change and so no data will be displayed. In questions like this such things are important.

Comment: Setting a UI (MainWindow in this case) as datacontext is really against MVVM. You cannot reuse/exchange your viewmodel without touching the UI which is one of the biggest advantages of MVVM

Answer (score 3):

```
{Binding Source=RowItems}
```

doesn't bind to a property `RowItems`.

You need to use

```
 {Binding RowItems}
```

Also make sure the property `RowItems` in your ViewModel is of type `ObservableCollection` as it notifies the UI that there are changes in the Collection, which a normal `List` doesn't. 
(You will need this if you modify data in the list after it is bound)

Comment: To add to this answer (as I believe it is probably the solution), reading up on [property change notification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-implement-property-change-notification) may also be helpful.

Comment: Yes, the problem is with Binding to RowItems property, so there are two correct answers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that your binding source (class)'s access modifier is set to public.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `Source` from the binding of `ItemsSource` in `DataGrid` and remove `"ClientListViewModel"` from `DataContext`.

```
<DataGrid                 
        AutoGenerateColumns="True"
        CanUserAddRows="False"
        CanUserReorderColumns="True"
        CanUserResizeColumns="True"
        ItemsSource="{Binding RowItems}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Given Name" Binding="{Binding GivenName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Family Name" Binding="{Binding FamilyName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Gender" Binding="{Binding Gender, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date of Birth" Binding="{Binding DateOfBirth, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

By default, bindings inherit the data context specified by the DataContext property, if one has been set. However, the Source property is one of the ways you can explicitly set the source of a Binding and override the inherited data context.
If you set

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Source=RowItems}"
```

then `RowItems` is translated to string (with lenght 8) and therefore you see eight lines.